# Exception thrown when trying to map with automapper and castle windsor injection

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, automapper

I get the following error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
RegistrationViewModel -> Member
```

Here's my models

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my mapper

```
public class MemberMapper : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, Member>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Address, y => y.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Gender, y => y.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Here's my [windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/) installer (that I copied from [github](https://gist.github.com/jochenjonc/1852705))

```
public class AutoMapperInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ConfigurationStore>()
                .OnlyNewServices()
                .ImplementedBy<ConfigurationStore>()
                // .Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll) // Uncomment this line to fix the problem (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/castle-project-users/FotV-tBtGiQ/id31pps10EsJ)
                .DependsOn(
                    Property.ForKey<ITypeMapFactory>().Eq(new TypeMapFactory()),
                    Property.ForKey<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>().Eq(MapperRegistry.AllMappers())
                ),
            Component.For<IConfigurationProvider>()
                .OnlyNewServices()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>())
                .LifeStyle.Singleton,
            Component.For<IConfiguration>()
                .OnlyNewServices()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>())
                .LifeStyle.Singleton,
            Component.For<IMappingEngine>()
                .OnlyNewServices()
                .ImplementedBy<MappingEngine>()
                .LifeStyle.Singleton,
            Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<MemberMapper>()
                .BasedOn<Profile>().WithServiceBase()
            );

        var profiles = container.ResolveAll<Profile>();
        var config = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();

        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            config.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling to figure out what's going wrong here, in the method I call the `IMappingEngine` looks good and isn't missing anything obvious from looking through the debug object explorer.

```
public MemberService(IGenericRepository<Member> repository, IMappingEngine mapper) :
        base(repository)
{
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

public void SaveNewUser(RegistrationViewModel registrationViewModel)
{
    var newMember = mapper.Map<Member>(registrationViewModel);

    ...
}
```

I get the feeling I might be massively over-complicating this but I really want to be able to inject `IMapperEngine` so that I can mock it out in my unit tests.  Without that I'm going to have to bin [automapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: I don't have the answer for you but may this will help you: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/12/automapper-and-ioc/

Comment: You might be right, I tried to follow that through earlier on today but didn't seem to help.  I should probably revisit it seeing as he did write automapper